# Is there a way to update mongodb from 2.4 to 2.6 in a raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to build a live chart out of a simple mongo colection, using Raspberry Pi 2 with dietPi (DietPi v6.22.3), mongodb and nodejs.

What I'm trying to do is to get data from the db using something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://IP:PORT/DATABASE';
var str = "";

app.route('/page_A').get(function (req, res) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Connected to db");
            var cursor = db.collection('COLLECTION_X').find();
            //noinspection JSDeprecatedSymbols
            cursor.each(function (err, item) {

                if (item != null) {
                    str = str + "    DateTime  " + item.dt + " - Users:  " + item.users + " </br>";
                }
            });
            res.send(str);
            db.close();
        }
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {});
```

Running node app.js and accessing the designated IP:8080/page_A I get the following error:

```
(node:3920) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
{ MongoError: Server at IP:PORT reports maximum wire version 0, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6)
    at checkSupportedServer (/PATH_Y/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:100:10)
    at runCommand (/PATH_Y/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:137:32)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/PATH_Y/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:334:5)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at processMessage (/PATH_Y/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:364:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/PATH_Y/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:533:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10) name: 'MongoError', [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Aparently I can't use these methods on this mongoDB version. 
Is there any way to get it updated to 2.6?

Here are some details on my setup:

```
mongod --version
db version v2.4.14

node --version
v10.15.3


cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

cat /etc/debian_version
9.8

uname -a
Linux DietPi 4.14.98+ #1200 Tue Feb 12 20:11:02 GMT 2019 armv6l GNU/Linux

cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : 000e
Serial          : 00000000ce0ee037
```

(and also tried to update mongo without success)

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

Thank you,

eunito.

Comment: See also [Upgrade MongoDB past 2.4.10](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79408/upgrade-mongodb-past-2-4-10) on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/. Also see [Node.js Driver Compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility) since there is also nothing stopping you using an older and compatible driver version, but it would be a very old one. None of the actual code used in your question **requires** a newer MongoDB version.

Comment: Thank Neil, but the table you mentioned refers "The driver does not support older versions of MongoDB." (the oldest seems to be 2.6.0)

Comment: The "matrix" shows the earliest version of the driver supporting MongoDB 2.6, but there are earlier releases than that available through `npm`. i.e even `'0.9.1'` can still be installed. The main point of note is that MongoDB is not producing 32-bit builds anymore, and only extended a few versions past even for Windows. There may be "unofficial" builds around as the other link content does in fact say if you decided to go for that option.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to search how to downgrade node to a compatible version then! :)

Comment: It's not `NodeJS` that needs the downgrade, it's the `mongodb` driver for NodeJS. You install specific versions by specifying the version number i.e `npm install mongodb@0.9.1`. But please don't install that version, but just the most recent version that actually still supports MongoDB 2.4. Probably something in the `1.2.x` series.

Comment: Thank you for your patience Neil! I'll give it a try. couldn't find a reference to that 1.2 series but will be using trial/error!